# AttributeError : module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'

Tags: tensorflow

I followed instructions (https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html) to install the Tensorflow Object Detection API. I use Anaconda on ubuntu18.4 and all of the steps in the instructions seemed to complete OK.

When I train to train my model with the following command:

```
python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn --pipeline_config_path=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn/pipeline.config
```

I get the following error:

```
Instructions for updating:
non-resource variables are not supported in the long term
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 34, in <module>
    from object_detection import model_lib_v2
  File "/home/chanitda/Desktop/Tensorflow/workspace/training_demo/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 28, in <module>
    from object_detection import eval_util
  File "/home/chanitda/Desktop/Tensorflow/workspace/training_demo/object_detection/eval_util.py", line 30, in <module>
    slim = tf.contrib.slim
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'
```

I get the error mentioned in the headline. I would be very thankful if someone could help me with a code example to solve the problem.

Comment: what's your tensorflow version?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the tensorflow 2.0 version, but the code you use needs tf 1.14. The module `contrib` is not available in tf 2.0 anymore, thats why you are seeing this error. So you should set up a new environment and install tf 1.14 there, so you can run the code properly without ruining your tf 2.0 environment